# Perl's Getop::Long equivalent in Python: options with multiple values

Tags: python

In Perl, there is a

```
Getopt::Long
```

module that has facility to pass multiple values to an option. Example, below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
my $fileList = "";
GetOptions("file_list=s@" => $fileList);
if($fileList) {
 foreach my $f (@$fileList) {
  # process each file's contents
 }
}
```

Is there anything equivalent in Python to do the same? I understand parsing each option and its values by myself and do whatever, with the files.  But I am looking for something right out of the box, like similar to what we have in Perl.

Comment: Sorry, the above code needs one small addition:  it should have been "foreach  my $f" instead of "foreach $f"

Comment: You could just press [edit] link under the question tags

Comment: Thank you, soon. Looks like I have become blind, working all night into the morning :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with Python `argparse`. From the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

> 'append' - This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple times. Example usage:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 --foo 2'.split())
Namespace(foo=['1', '2'])
```

So your example would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--file_list', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.file_list:
    for f in args.file_list:
        print f
```

And you can run it with `python ./myscript.py --file_list a --file_list b --file_list c`.

Comment: Thank you Benedikt.  This will do.  Have a great evening/day.